# Show combobox drop down while editing text

Tags: vb.net, combobox, event-handling

When I first load my form the combobox functions as desired:

[image]

Then when I select one of the drop down menu items (via cursor or arrow keys & enter):

[image]

Now if I try to edit the text in the combo box again (via cursor or arrow keys), the drop down menu no longer appears:

[image]

Currently my load form method:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'connect to RFDB
    Dim connectionString = My.Settings.RFDBConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()

    'Get Versions Table from RFDB
    Dim versions As DataTable
    Dim query = "select LocationID, VersionsNum, Description, PlanetExport from Versions inner join VersionsBuild on VersionsBuildID=IDVersionsBuild"
    versions = QueryRFDB(query, connectionString)

    'Fill ComboBox with possible site versions
    Dim source As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To versions.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim siteVersion As String
        siteVersion = versions.Rows(i)(0) & " V" & versions.Rows(i)(1) & " " & versions.Rows(i)(2)
        source.Add(siteVersion)
    Next i
    Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source
    Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource


    'Fill ListBox with currently flagged site versions
    For i = 0 To versions.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim siteVersion As String
        siteVersion = versions.Rows(i)(0) & " V" & versions.Rows(i)(1) & " " & versions.Rows(i)(2)
        If versions.Rows(i)(3) = True Then Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(siteVersion)
    Next i

End Sub

'Returns a data table as the result of the sql query on RFDB
Private Function QueryRFDB(ByVal query As String, ByVal connectionString As String)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(table)
    Return table
End Function
```

I am thinking it is maybe a settings issue with my combobox? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your 1. 2. 3. points are unclear. Please elaborate more. Dropping ComboBox has two variants : Non editable Dropping List (DropDownList) and editable (DropDown). However, entering a missing item in the editable one doesn't retain that entry. Adding entries is done programmaticaly. I'm not able to show the drop down even by pressing the Enter Key (Only up/down arrow keys are of use - win7/winforms) ie, are you doing that through a piece of code ? (means do you have a piece of code we can have a look at ? (Just to show you how unclear is your question)

Comment: i just tested this with an unbound combobox and it works without a problem. DropDownStyle = DropDown / AutoCompleteSource = ListItems / AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend. So i guess it has something to do with your code